# Fuzzy search on a collection of strings

Tags: search, lucene, fuzzy-search, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search and I have an index that has a field named 'keywords', which holds keywords (with type Collection(Edm.String)) related to a single document. I want to be able to use fuzzy search on my documents and as I understood from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_fuzzy) link, all I have to do is put a '~' character to the end of my search query. However, this doesn't seem to work in my case.

I have a few documents in my index and one of them includes "fun" in its keywords. When I search for "run" with fuzzy search, I expect to see the documents with keyword "run", as well as "fun". If I know correctly, the edit distance between "fun" and "run" is only 1, which seems to be the default distance Azure Search's fuzzy search uses. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Or does the type Collection(Edm.String) not support fuzzy search? The attributes for 'keywords' are Searchable, Filterable and Retrievable.

Edit: I'm using the Standard Lucene Analyzer for the 'keywords' field. When I send the query

```
https://fakename.search.windows.net/indexes/fakeindex/docs?api-version=2016-09-01&search=run~
```

I would expect to get the following document as its keywords contain "fun"

```
"keywords": [
    "balloon",
    "message",
    "text",
    "monster",
    "fun",
    "evil",
    "mad",
    "cartoons",
    "funny"
  ]
```

Comment: Which analyzer are you using for the field? The fuzzy operator ~ should be put at the end of the search term. Could you share the search query and one document thats's expected to match?

Comment: @NateKo I edited the question to include the info you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fuzzy search feature is only supported in Lucene query syntax in Azure Search. Please specify queryType=full in the query string.